# Test with no operator?

Tags: shell

A simple question : 
What is the advantage of a test using a test operator versus one directly testing the variable?
As follows :

```
[ -n "$foo" ] && echo "that's some variable :"$foo || echo '$foo is blank.'
```

versus

```
[ $foo ] && echo "that's some variable :"$foo || echo '$foo is blank.'
```

The second is more elegant. But I suspect there must be a reason, because someone went to the trouble of making "-z" and "-n" exist.

Comment: [What is the rationale for closing "why" questions on a language design?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170394/what-is-the-rationale-for-closing-why-questions-on-a-language-design) -- Stack Overflow is a place for specific, *practical* questions. A question whose answer does not change how you go about the practice of programming is not practical.

Comment: BTW, see [BashPitfalls #22](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#cmd1_.26.26_cmd2_.7C.7C_cmd3) re: `foo && bar || baz`; it is absolutely not identical to `if foo; then bar; else baz; fi`.

Comment: And `[ $foo ]` is simply incorrect. Consider what happens if `foo='-z 1'`; string-splitting makes it `if [ -z 1 ]`, so you get an answer of false even though the string is non-empty (which would make `[ "$foo" ]`, with quotes added, true).

Comment: no advantages. According to test manual page,
0 arguments: The expression is false.
1 argument: The expression is true if and only if the argument is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect `[ "$foo" ]` (quote the parameter expansion) is supported for historical reasons; once upon a time, saving two bytes by omitting the explicit, commonly used, `-n` could be significant.

Today, I would *always* use `-n` explicitly for clarity.

Note that you should not combine `&&` and `||` for a "one-line" conditional statement. Use an `if` statement.

```
if [ -n "$foo" ]; then
  echo "that's some variable: $foo"
else
  echo "foo is blank."
fi
```